# Did it create VM?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

So i'm new to Azure - Registered about a hour ago. 
I created Free Trial account but connected my Card to it so i could get 200$ for Trial.
+++
I tried to create UbuntuNC24 VM - Wanted to see its hash rate (NOT for CryptoCurrency).

Its very expensive VM ~ 9$/h but I got that 200$ for testing so I wanted to see how would it perform.

But when I created everything and clicked "Finis" or however that last button is called I got some API error.
After that I refreshed page and it was on "Dashboard" as creating/starting... And then it disappeared from there.

I looked under VM in menu and on all Resources and its not there. Like I did not created it.

My question is - Did i create it and if I did where did it go? 
I guess it would be very expensive mistake to just leave it..

Its debit card with 2$ balance on it but I don't want to hog on VM if I'm not using it or to go in debt with Azure (if it's possible).

Comment: If you don't see it in the "All Resources" section then it was not created and you won't be charged. I have never seen an Azure Resource fail to be created though. Do you recall what the API Message said? It may not be available under a trial subscription since NC24r v2 4X P100 VM is $9.30 per hour in a pay-as-you-go model.

Comment: I don't know what message it was but its not logged anywhere.
- But under Monitor -> Activity log I found:
Error code
InvalidTemplateDeployment
Message
The template deployment 'Canonical.UbuntuServer1604LTS-20180219225349' is not valid according to the validation procedure. 

So u guess it's not created.

Comment: Yes, it appears something went wrong in the creation of the VM (maybe from the VHD image). I would create a Support Request (on the toolbar in the portal, click the question mark icon, and then the Help + Support button). I would paste the Activity Log message and also express your concern over being billed. You should be fine...

Comment: Tnx for answer!
Its stupid idea to mess with expensive stuff without experience when I have free basic VM to test on :D

Comment: If you can't see the resource, not it wasn't created. When an error occurs in one of the deployment steps, usually the step after is to clean up anything that was built. Also, there's a spend limit by default on new trial accounts. Unless you manually remove that limit, you will never get charged on your credit card.